# How do 'C' statements execute inside memory

Tags: c, statements

Suppose I have this piece of *C* code here:

```
int main() {           
    int a = 10;
    printf("test1");
    printf("test2");
    someFunc();
    a = 20;
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

Well I think that all these statements are stored on the stack at a time and then popped one by one to get executed. Am I correct? If not, please correct me.

Comment: *Usually* the code is translated to *machine code* by the compiler, and then the CPU executes the machine code from top to bottom (not considering jumps). Local variables are commonly stored on the stack, CPU machine instructions are not. Just about all compilers have options to save the generated machine code as assembly code (which is machine code using "nice" names for the CPU instructions), you might want to take a look at that, and learn more about it. I also recommend you read more about the low-level architecture of a computer, and how they work internally.

Comment: CPUs don't understand statements. They only read [instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set)

Comment: I would strongly recommend any would-be programmer to study basic assembler, to understand how programs and computers actually work. You are not really a programmer until you know this - for the same reasons as why you aren't a car mechanic just because you can drive a car.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for suggesting.....I really appreciate...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really no. The C standard doesn't mention a *stack* so your notions are ill-conceived.

A C compiler (or interpreter for that matter) can do anything it likes so long as it follows the C standard.

In your case, that could mean, among other things, (i) the removal of `a` altogether, since it's only used to output 20 at the end of the function, and (ii) `someFunc()` could be removed if there are no side effects in doing so.

What *normally* happens is that your code is converted to machine code suitable for the target architecture. These machine code instructions do tend to follow the code quite faithfully (C in this sense is quite "low level") although modern compilers will optimise aggressively.

Comment: I like your explanation but I would like to make myself more clear.Just in case of a recursive call,the statements after the recursive call in a method are stored in stack,isn't it possible that these statements execute the same way?Stored in stack and getting popped.....Please explain

Comment: It *might* do. On the other hand the compiler might unpick the recursion, particularly if it spots *tail recursion*.

Comment: Ya in case of tail recursion , it might as there is nothing after the recursive call.So in short , there is no guarantee as to how the compiler executes the above piece of code.Am I correct?

Comment: Yup. No guarantee at all. Just the guarantee that the C standard is obeyed.

Comment: @Reckoner Implementation is never guaranteed. The only thing you can count on is that your compiler follows c standard. Anything in between is up to the compiler.

Comment: @Reckoner: The statements are almost never stored in a stack and popped, in all implementations of C so far (if someone knows different feel free to give an example otherwise). Instead, variables are stored in the stack. Recursion does not require the statements (instructions) to be stored in a stack, only the variables.

Comment: @slebetman let's take this example:
      
recursiveFunction(int collect){
          
    if(collect == 1) return;
 collect--;   
 recursiveFunction(collect);
printf("%d",collect);
}

Well here all the print statements will be executed after the base condition is met(popped one by one from stack) . Does that mean only the variable 'collect' is stored everytime at an address with a different value?

Comment: @Reckoner: Yes, that function is compiled only in one place in memory. It's not in any stack and there are no multiple copies. There is only one copy (which is why there is no need for a stack of instructions). When that function is called, that function call basically does: `goto address_of_recursiveFunction` then when you recurse it does a `goto address_of_recursiveFunction`. No stack.

Comment: @slebetman So no stack even for the variable 'collect'?Are you sure?

Comment: @Reckoner: Like I said. The stack is only for the variables, not statements/instructions

Comment: @Reckoner: Would you like me to explain how the program stack work in an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The C standard doesn't specify where things go in memory.

However, computers work like this in general:

- Your program consists of various memory sections/segments, usually they are called `.data`, `.bss`, `.rodata`, `.stack`, `.text` and there is possibly also a `.heap`. The `.text` section is for storing the actual program code, the rest of the sections are for storing variables. [More info on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment).
- The C code is translated to machine code (assembler) by the compiler. All code is stored inside the `.text` section, which is read-only memory.
- Modern computers can "mark" memory as either code or data, and will be capable of generating hardware exceptions if you try to execute code in the data section, or treat the code section as data. This way the processor can assist in catching bugs like dangling pointers or run-away code.
- In theory you could execute code from any memory section, even on the stack, but because of the previously mentioned feature, this is not typically done. Most often, it wouldn't make any sense to do so anyhow.

So for your specific code snippet, the only thing that is stored on the stack is the variable `a`. Or more likely, it is stored in a CPU register, for performance reasons.

The string literals `"test1"`, `"test2"` and `"%d"` will be stored in the `.rodata` section.

The literal `20` could either be stored in the `.rodata` section, or more likely, merged into the code and therefore stored in `.text` together with the rest of the code.

The *program counter* determines which part of the code that is currently executed. The stack is not involved in that what-so-ever, it is only for storing data.

Answer (score 1):

Whats worth noting is that the C standard does not mandate implementation. So as long as the output is correct according to the standard, the compiler is free to implement this as it choses.

What most likely happens for you is that the compiler translates this bit of C into assembler code which is then executed top to bottom.

```
a = 20;
```

Is most likely optimised out unless you use it somewhere else. Good compilers also throw a warning for you like:

> Warning: Unused Variable a